# How do I use Razor to render, edit, and post an variable set of parameters in ASP.NET MVC? Array[] or List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Imagine I have a shopping list, where I don't know how many items will be rendered on the screen, but need to support a long and growing list for view and edit.

How do I [create such a form](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) so that I can render it in ASP.NET MVC 4, and also edit it?

Assume my model has an array or a list that I would like to have multiple text boxes for editing:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to create an editortemplate.
Say you class is named `Product`, create a partial view named "Product.cshtml" under the folder `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`.

**Note:** These names are important, as MVC will look in that specific folder for that specific view name by convention.

Now you can do the following in your view:

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Although your calling the editor here for a list of products, MVC is smart enough to recognize that it should invoke the editor for each item of the list. Also, if you use an editor-template, it will make sure that the ID's and names will be set correctly so that the model binder can later reconstruct the list when you post the values to your controller.

**Partial view**

```
@model Product
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
```

You action method (the one you post the form to) would then look like this:

```
public ActionResult PostList(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    // Do whatever a dev's gotta do
}
```